# What is the difference between a pointer to a pointer and the addressof a pointer in C?

Tags: c

What is the difference between initializing a variable *x* as char ** and initializing a variable *x* as char * and then using *&* to reference it?  This question came up from the following inquiry:

I was looking at the **man 3 strtol** function.  The function signature is:

```
long strtol(const char *restrict str, char **restrict endptr, int base);
```

So, to pass the **endptr** variable, I setup a variable:

```
char **endptr;
```

but when I passed it to the function it always returned NULL, even in cases where the **str** passed to **strtol** was something like *abc*. 
 I.E:

```
         char ** endptr;
         long exitval = strtol(args[1], endptr, 10); /* try to get the val */
         if (endptr != NULL) { /* it wasn't a valid base-10 number */
```

Yet when I changed how I initialized endptr to:

```
char *endptr;
```

and then passed the **endptr** as *&endptr* to the function, **endptr** was set correctly. I.E:

```
         char * endptr;
         long exitval = strtol(args[1], &endptr, 10); /* try to get the val */
         if (endptr != NULL) { /* it wasn't a valid base-10 number */
```

In both cases, I thought was I was passing was the *a pointer to a pointer to the first char in a char array*, but the fact that one method works and the other doesn't indicates my understanding is incorrect.

**Why does one method work and the other doesn't? What am I misunderstanding?**

Comment: How did you initialize `**endptr`?

Comment: A typical use of `strtol` might be `char* endptr = NULL; long l = strtol(buf, &endptr, 10);` and the Linux [strtol(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) man page gives a full example.

Comment: @minitech, editied the Q to include the two versions of the code used.

Comment: Well, in the new version, endpointer points to nothing (it is uninitialised) . It should point to a character pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have a shot.

The function `strtol` wants the address of something it can write to.

When you declare

```
char *ptr;
```

you have a variable called `ptr` and when you pass its address, `strtol` can write to that location and afterward you can use that value by looking at the contents of the variable.

When you declare

```
char **ptr;
```

and just pass its value, first of all you're probably passing an uninitialised value that `strtol` will try to write to, and secondly, even if you initialise it you're passing just it's contents - `strtol` will modify the location it points to, not the contents of the variable itself.

Comment: Thank for the answer.  A bit of a follow up: when you say "you're passing just it's contents - strtol will modify the location it points to, not the contents of the variable itself", do you mean I'm passing the uninitialized value of **ptr?

Comment: @Nate - Yes. If you don't pass the address of the variable, there's no way for `strtol` to modify it, just like when you pass an integer variable to a function as an argument, setting that parameter to another value doesn't change the value of the variable outside the function when you return.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! This clears up another Q I was thinking about re: parameters--if when you pass a parameter to a function the function is aware of both the address of the parameter as well as the value of the parameter, and extrapolating from your answer, it looks like the function is aware of only one or the other.

Comment: @Nate - That's correct - if you pass the address, you can dereference using `*` inside the function and change the value at that address. The address itself that was passed in is like a local variable, and changing it has no effect outside the function, just like any other parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In the first you are not giving a value to your pointer to a pointer, it is an uninitialised value you are passing to strtol, in the second you are defining a pointer and then you are getting the address of it, so you are passing the address of endptr.

Another way to think about it is, the first example you are defining a place in memory that is to holds a pointer to a pointer, but that memory is not set to anything, you are then passing that garbage to strol. The second one you are defining a place in memory that holds a pointer, you are then getting the address of the bit of memory and then passing it to strol.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page :

> If  endptr  is  not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first invalid character in *endptr.

In the first case you pass the value of `endptr` to `strtol()` which was initialized to 0, so `strtol()` will not store the address of the first invalid character in `*endptr`.

In the second case you pass the address of `endptr` to `strtol()`, which is not 0, thus it will not return NULL if an invalid character is found.

Comment: thanks.  Your answer makes a lot of sense--I was unclear on the exact difference of passing address versus value.